# "Notification Email Template" a new section is automatically being added to Emails Send via Publisher Action

Tags: visualforce, email, email-template, publisher-action

Found that the custom email publisher action i.e. on a VF page with apex email publisher is adding a new item to the body email by itself .The email template is a custom one with Encoding:UTF-8,Tempalte Type:Custom.

Has anybody come across this issue yet ?

Is there a solution for this ? I am searching for one , will post it if I am able to deduce.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Salesforce:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jgjpAAA

**EmailMessages show HTML mark-up in the feed view**

Summary
Case Console Feed View email tracking is showing HTML mark-up with emails sent from/received to the case related lists, as of Spring '16.

Repro
1) Enable Email-To-Case 
2) Enable HTML emails 
3) Send an HTML email from the related list of a case 
4) View the case feed in the console and see the email history looks something like this: "p{margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;}Test"

Workaround
You would be able to send the email from the case feed actions and this will still display normally.

**Edited on 9th March 2016:**
Got message from Salesforce that the issue is fixed.